# How do I place toolbar below collapsingtoolbarlayout when expanded?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, appbar

I have the following code below on which I'm trying to make a collapsible toolbar that will make the toolbar which has a linearlayout inside, to stick to the bottom part of the layout when expanded.

I have been moving parts/layouts all around for several hours trying to make it stick to the bottom and still show at the appbar even when closed/pushed up but I cant make it show up as I intended.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivProfileAvatar"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/profile_image" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvUserUsername"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="SomeName"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="UniversityName"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="tvUserStatus"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="16dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnEditProfile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_gradient_blue"
                android:paddingEnd="48dp"
                android:paddingStart="48dp"
                android:text="Edit Profile"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabsProfile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:tabBackground="@null"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tabProfileMyLikes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tabProfileMyPosts"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท the toolbar actually has a linearlayout inside. I'm able to make it stick using collapse mode pin on the toolbar, but then, it always sticks to the top, which defeats my goal of making it stay at the bottom of the whole collapsible toolbar, and only sticking at the top when they collapsible toolbar is pushed up or closed.

Comment: `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is a collapsible view and it's usually at the top of the `Activity` so you shouldn't expect to make other views under `CollapsingToolbarLayout` stick at bottom. Instead, you'll need to check my answer and add the view inside `CoordinatorLayout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `TabLayout` inside `Toolbar` and that's not a good design and wrong (i should say).

Instead, try something like this:

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabsProfile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:tabBackground="@null"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tabProfileMyLikes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tabProfileMyPosts"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

To make a view pinned or stick somewhere, using `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` will help or instead, add the view to `CoordinatorLayout` like `FloatingActionButton` position to make it stick in the bottom and set: `android:gravity` to `bottom`.

Comment: I'm able to make it stick using the collapsemode pin, but it always stays at the top even when the collapsible toolbar is open. What I'm trying to do is like facebook's interface where the navigation stays at the top when you scroll down, but the search bar and messenger icon shows up above the navigation when you pull up.

Comment: The reason I have a tablayout inside is because I have a viewpager at the main layout. I'm trying to make the tablayout still show up at the toolbar when the user scrolls down.

Comment: It's doing it's work properly actually. You may wanna try adding `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"` instead of `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` to see if this is what you want.

Comment: I tried parallax but it vanishes along with the whole layout. I'll keep testing til I make it work.

Comment: I got it working by setting linearlayout gravity and the toolbar layout gravity

Answer (score -2):

Use the below code I hope it  will help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <include layout="@layout/record_description_header" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="230dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/bcslogo2"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```